# Gson - store source JSON in every converted object

Tags: android, json, gson

Let's say I have JSON like this:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

and POJO like this:

```
class MyClass extends Base{
  int a;
}

class Base 
{
  JsonElement originalElement; // or String originalJson;
}
```

I want to save original JSON to every class which extends 'Base', so after conversion I could get the original source, even if my Java class doesn't have all JSON's field. I know that I could use 'setJson' every time, but I am wondering if there's possibility to do automatically with JsonDeserializer or any other library's element.

EDIT:
I want to avoid code like this

```
MyClass object= gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
object.setJson(json);
// if class has nested classes which extends Base: 
object.getNestedObject().setJson(json.get("nested"));
```

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming you want to save the information of objects into a json string. The issue still comes back with retrieval. You could use `JSONSerializer` to serialize a `HashMap<String, Base>`  and then get them by key (object name?) based on which one you want. But you'd still need to deserialize it to another HashMap and know the key value. I'm not sure what specific problem you're trying to solve so I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: I am getting some JSONs from server with several fields. I am using only few of them and I don't know all fields names so I am serializing only part of JSON (just like in my example). Issue is that I have to send this JSON further, so I have to use original JSON instead of serializing my Java class. Is that clear?

Comment: If those classes are subclasses of Base, then creating/setting the static variable string for json in the Base class will make it available in any subclass. So if the Base class has a static variable `origJson`. Then doing `Base.setJson(json)` will make it so that any subclass of Base has a variable named origJson set to the value of json. So if it is static, you set it once and you can access it from any subclass.

Comment: I don't want to have one 'origJson' for all objects but it keep seperate for every converted object. Every converted object has own original JSON (obviously).

Comment: Then intrinsically, you'd have to set it for each one if they are all supposed to be unique. You could make a generic method that inside it, uses a JSONSerializer to just set it's internal json variable to a json string representing itself. Then every subclass would inherit that method and have a way to create the json string without needing to get it again.

Comment: Can I use JSONDeserializer to store original JSON source every time object gets parsed by Gson object?

Comment: You could make a wrapper class for the GSON parser that does that when you call fromJSON, but you're really only saving yourself one function call per object. I'd just make the method in the base class and call it each time I make a new object so it's clear what the code is doing, but it's up to you at that point. Let me know if that helps you and I'll put it up as answer you can accept.

Comment: I've done the same thing. However - there is one big issue - how this wrapper class could handle nested objects which have base class? I can call 'fromJSON' but it doesn't give any control on actual conversion, so nested objects stay without JSON source.

Comment: Well assuming that you are forming them with JSON, inside the `setJson()` method, I wouldn't even try to pass it the full JSON string as it is already formed from it. I would just call `String origJson = new JSONSerializer().serialize(this)`. It should be the exact same thing as you built the object from a json string and you're just getting that representation.

Comment: And you could cascade that `setJson()` on all sub-objects as well.

Comment: I need to have partial JSONs for nested objects. How could I cascade on all sub-objects extending Base class? Using reflection.. ? In addition, I don't want to convert object inside setJson method, this method is used only to save original source as a String/JsonElement. Gson wrapper class would be in charge of that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23374/discussion-between-chad-campbell-and-piotr)